# Node custom-environment-variables.js is not working from Netbeans 17

Tags: node.js, netbeans

I am trying to make a small node.js application with netbeans 17.
I want to use custom-environment-variable.json to use a secret from environment variable.
I have a config folder and inside it there is

1. default.json
2. custom-environemnt-variables.json

Contents of default.json are:

```
{
      "jwtPrivateKey": ""
}
```

and contents or custom-environment-variables are:

```
{
      "jwtPrivateKey": "recyclebin_jwtPrivateKey"
}
```

where recyclebin_jwtPrivateKey has the value "recycleBinSecureKey".

Now the strange think is when I start my applicatoin from command line like this:
"node mains.js" the application works fine.

When I start the application from within netbeans using the play button the environment variable is never read.
Does anyone knows if netbeans needs some specific configuration for this feature?

Thanks in advance.